# PHP: ob_start(), how to limit callback

Tags: php, ob-start

How does one stop calls to the `ob_start` callback when issue-ing `*_clean()` calls.

```
ob_start(function($buffer, $phase){
    // code here
}, 0, PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE | PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE);
```

Doesn't prevent `ob_end_clean`, `ob_get_clean` or `ob_clean` calls from being ran.
I'd expect a notice that the buffer wasn't started with the proper `PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE` flag
as per the [docs](http://php.net/manual/ro/function.ob-end-clean.php).

As for the `PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_*` constants, I haven't found a suitable man page where the `$phase` parameter is explained and the groups of bits pertaining to those constants detailed. Even the actual names / values I've had to get them from the CONSTANTS global variable.

```
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_START
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_WRITE
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSH
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEAN
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FINAL
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CONT
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_END
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_CLEANABLE
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_FLUSHABLE
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_REMOVABLE
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_STDFLAGS
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_STARTED
PHP_OUTPUT_HANDLER_DISABLED
```

Knowing these constants I've tried to limit so that no clean methods trigger my callback and short-circuit its logic. But I couldn't get the `$phase` content for any of the clean methods out (can't call printf, echo,ob_start from within the callback).

Maybe I'm going at this wrong, my scenario is:

- I start a buffer at the beginning to process all output later
- A lot of code that I don't control runs:

  `for ($i = 0; $i < ob_get_level(); $i++) {  $final .= ob_get_clean(); }`
- Triggers my callback even though it shouldn't as the code is not its owner / no cleanable flag was set
- I trigger alerts for empty buffers even though it isn't the case as they reconstruct it in another buffer

Basically my questions are:

- Am I able to stop such a thing?
- If not is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

If you have code which clears the whole buffer and you cannot control it - there's no way you get ob_* commands to work properly. You can implement your own buffer construction though and add output there manually.

The class might look like this

```
<?php

class MyBuffer
{
    static $buffer = '';

    public static function add(string $output)
    {
        self::$buffer .= $output;
    }

    public static function get()
    {
        return self::$buffer;
    }

    public static function get_clean()
    {
        $buffer = self::$buffer;
        self::$buffer = '';
        return $buffer;
    }
}
```

An you could use it in the following way

```
// ... some code
MyBuffer::add('Hello user, glad you joined us!');
// ... some more code
MyBuffer::add('Your socore is ' . $score . '. Congratz!');
// ...
echo MyBuffer::get_clean();
```